# drf create manytomany fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[image]

models

```py
class CreatorRawArtwork(models.Model):
    id         = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title      = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    descripton = models.TextField()
    editions   = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    price      = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    medias     = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="raw-medias")
    user       = models.ForeignKey(to=Login, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creatorrawartwork", null=True, blank=True
    )
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
    to=DesignerCollection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creatorrawartwork", null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(DesignerCategories, related_name='creatorrawartwork')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializer

```py
class CreatorRawArtworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=DesignerCategories.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CreatorRawArtwork
        fields = "__all__"
        depth=1
```

views

```py
class CreatorRawArtworkView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CreatorRawArtwork.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreatorRawArtworkSerializer
```

Here i am trying to create manytomany fields using drf serialier it is showing some error
plese check the screenshot for parameter and responses

What can be the issue please take a look

Comment: by `create manytomany fields`, do you mean you want to create `DesignerCategories` object with 1 and 2 as value...?? or just want to attach it in `CreatorRawArtwork` object...??

Comment: [1,2] i will send categories like this. because catgory already created

Comment: you might be getting it in the form of string. convert it into list by doing json.loads()...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I tested with your code and your code is working fine
just make sure your request data is json

Answer (score 0):

```
class CreatorRawArtworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        collection = DesignerCollectionSerializer(read_only=True) #assuming you have already defined serializer for *DesignerCollectionSerializer*
        categories = DesignerCategoriesSerializer(many=True)

        class Meta:
            model = CreatorRawArtwork
            fields = "__all__"
            depth=1
```